# Jquery load in Dialog is repeated exponentially

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, load

I have a really annoying issue with jQuery and/or the jQuery UI Dialog Box.

After clicking on a special link a modal dialog will pop up with some loaded content (ajax) and inside this loaded content are new links/buttons that load their url inside the same div Box, so the dialog still is loaded, but with new content then. The Problem is, that if you link on that link (inside a fresh loaded dialog box and on a recently reloaded website) it works as it should, but with the second click it loads the url twice, with the third it loads 4 times ... It growing exponentially with every new link loaded inside the dialog. I testet this with a counter stored inside $_SESSION.

This is the Javascript Code:

```
var somedialog = $('<div></div>').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  resizable: false,
  modal: true,
  /*show: 'fade',
  hide: 'puff',*/
  closeOnEscape: true,
  close: function(){
  }
 });
 function openInDialog(url, title, width, height)
 {
  somedialog.empty();
  somedialog.dialog("option", "width", width);
  somedialog.dialog("option", "height", height);
  somedialog.dialog("option", "title", title);
  somedialog.load(url,{},function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
   {
    somedialog.dialog('open');
   }
  );

  //somedialog.load(url,{},function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
  // dialogdiv.somedialog('open');
  //});
 }

 $('a.ajaxBuyItemDialog').on('click',function(){
  openInDialog(this.href, this.title, 400, 300);
  //prevent the browser to follow the link
  return false;
 });
```

There seemed to bee other people with this issue, but that was not a very effective discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471360/jquery-load-after-load-repeated-results-problem

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
This is part of the code which is located in the loaded script:

```
$("#_BUYITEM_FORM").live('submit', function(){
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function(response){ // on success..
            $("#_BUYITEM_CONTENT").html('<p class="AjaxLoaderImg"><span>Einen Moment bitte...</span></p>');
            $("#_BUYITEM_CONTENT").html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
    return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
```

Without it I can't get it to refresh the dialog box with new content.

Comment: is this code in url you are loading more than once?

Comment: edited the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Dirty" solution

```
function watchBuyItemForm(){
        $("#_BUYITEM_FORM").submit(function(){
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
                url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
                success: function(response){ // on success..
                    somedialog.html(ajaxLoader);
                    somedialog.html(response); // update the DIV
                    watchBuyItemForm();
                }
            });
            return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your javascript code is replicated in every `$('a.ajaxBuyItemDialog')` destination page clicked. Adding that script to the dialog again at every click causes event to be triggered more than once.

Answer (score 0):

If you reload the script numerous times it will add a new submit handler to form each time since you are using live().

live() will delegate the handler to the document and thus should either only be called once or you need to call die() before script loads each time.

if you were to get rid of using live() you could move the submit handler to the success callback of load() and use submit() rather than live(). If the original form is replaced...the original submit() event handler will also be gone

Comment: when you use delegation methods like live() the handler is delegated for future elements that match also. If you change what you have to `$("#_BUYITEM_FORM").submit(function(){` as long as you are replacing complete form your issue will stop

Comment: actually not sure what code is running where.. it may not be the submit, if you are continuaously loading the A tag click handler will be a problem also

Comment: At first the dialog is opened with a link using the openInDialog-function. In the dialog is a form (id=_BUYITEM_FORM). This form loads another form (id=_BUYITEM_FORM, could be changed if needed) into the dialog and replaces the old one. The new form loads the result page replacing the content in the dialog again. After this the dialog will be closed.
When the dialog is opened again, every form sends it's request two times. Closing the dialog and open it again the forms sends their requests three times.

Comment: you are loading he same code repeatedly either from within ajax loaded html of form..  or triggering the same handler repeatedly in ajax succeess

Comment: I posted a new answer. Is there a better way?

Comment: if it is working it is what I was suggesting a few comments ago. Not dirty at all